# What type of air filters are these? Are they any good?

Tags: heating, air-conditioning, air-filter

I'm pretty sure these air filters have been in the house for 30+ years.

I'm not sure what type of filters they are. Are they disposable or can you clean them?

Are they efficient at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like expanded stainless steel and that would make them completely reusable. I would hose them off and put them back in and save yourself some money. Unless you are sensitive and need a HEPA style filter these should work fine for most dust and hair.

Comment: Can you buy these types of filters brand new?

Comment: You can definitely buy reusable filters still, they are fairly popular.  Google "reusable home furnace air filter" for about 500,000 places that sell them.

Comment: Looks more like the passive electrostatic type (plastic mesh, rather open) to me. Still washable, probably more effective than stainless steel as an air filter. The large expanded metal mesh is just to support the plastic.

Comment: True. Now that I look closer I think you may be right. Looks like it has plastic between the metal. Not the old  stainless steel wool type.